# What is wrong with my JavaScript script code here?

Tags: javascript, html

JavaScript code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
                var listitems = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
                var newListItem = document.createElement('li');
                var newListItemText = document.createTextNode('Tutorials');
                newListItem.appendChild(newListItemText);
                listitems.appendChild(newListItem);

            </script>
```

**HTML Code:**

```
        <body>
        <div class="2div">
        <div id="navigator">
            <nav >
                <ul class="nav_menu">
                    <li><a href="/homepage.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Contact.html">Contact Info</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <div id="aboutme">
            <body>
                <p> This section will contain basic info about me</p>
            </body>
        </div>


    </div>
```

The error I'm receiving on my chrome console is this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined
```

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to find the element before it is on the page.

Comment: Check listitems if is undefined before to use it. Log it and you see that it's undefined.

Comment: Is your Javascript located above or below the HTML?  It needs to be below so that the `ul` tag will exist.

Comment: The HTML you added doesn't contain ul element.
Please edit your question if it wasn't your purpose

Comment: wow i understand. So i should start the script with $(document).ready(function... ) then? I kept searching if the appendChild() has been depreciated but it is still used. So the script should actually occur after the list has been created.

Answer (score 1):

Your probably loading the js file before the HTML so the `ul` element wasn't rendered yet.

You can use jQuery's `$(document).ready(function(){..Your code})` to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the onload function because you are working on HTML elements which are not in the DOM yet :

```
window.onload = function foo() {

var listitems = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
                var newListItem = document.createElement('li');
                var newListItemText = document.createTextNode('Tutorials');
                newListItem.appendChild(newListItemText);
                listitems.appendChild(newListItem);

}
```

See the result here : https://jsfiddle.net/vdf61qnw/

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'ul' in your html so

```
document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0] == null
```

Therefore listitems is null and cannot be appended to. This should append your JavaScript created elements:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
            var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
            var listitems = document.createElement('ul');
            var newListItem = document.createElement('li');
            var newListItemText = document.createTextNode('Tutorials');
            newListItem.appendChild(newListItemText);
            listitems.appendChild(newListItem);
            body.appendChild(listitems);
   </script>
```